# Unable to bind arguments and anchor tags in jquery

Tags: jquery, anchor

I am trying to create a basic "to-do" list in jQuery. I've gotten most of the program to work.

However, I am having trouble with my apostrophes and quotes.

I want to add some hyper-text which will exist to the right of the "to-do" item.

e.g `I'M A TO DO ITEM [edit text link that will allow one to edit TO DO][remove text]`

So, this hyper-text text will either allow the user to "edit" or "remove" the "to-do" item. If I use the code below, the "removeItem" appears outside of the `<li>`. I am getting quite frustrated and am hoping for some assistance.

```
$("#addButton").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var toDoItem= $(".tempText").val();
    $("#todoList").append('<li>'+toDoItem+'<a href="#" class="edit">'+ editItem +'</a>','<a href="#" class="remove">'+removeItem+'</a>','</li>');
    itemCount=itemCount+1;
    $("#count").text(itemCount);
    return(false);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a single string to `append()`, rather than a comma separated list of strings (so they aren't treated as individual elements, and won't be appended one *after* another):

```
'<li>' + toDoItem + '<a href="#" class="edit">' + editItem + '</a><a href="#" class="remove">' + removeItem + '</a></li>'
```

Comment: That works! Thanks for your help as I was getting really frustrated with my commas and apostrophes.